# JMSToolbox - can't connect to local IBM MQ queue manager - anyone got more info on config?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, jmstoolbox

I have a simple dev instance of IBM MQ 9.1.x. It's got the default setup on QM1 with the default user/password.

I have a JMS application that does connect already, but when I try JMSToolbox (latest 5.14.0) and I put the `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.0.0.jar` in the `jre/lib` folder, I get a proper MQ properties page and I put in the same values as my JMS app, it comes back and says:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

I feel like it's probably something simple, but I can't quite figure it out. I am fairly new to MQ.

Comment: What error do you see in the AMQERR01.LOG on the queue manager?

Comment: Reason code of 2035 is not authorized. Use setmqaut to give your UserId permission to connect & access the queue.

Comment: It could also be due to CONNAUTH or CHLAUTH

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to configure JMSToolBox to connect to IBM MQ is [documented here](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki/2.1-Setup-for-IBM-MQ)

The specific jars needed must be setup as [described here](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/wiki/1.1-Quick-Start#configuring-a-queue-provider) , via the`"Q Managers"`tab

You must not add jars to the jre\lib directory or elsewhere

As for the error you receive, its probable either a misconfigured user/password/channel in JMSToolBox or the user you are using does not have the right to access MQ

(I'm the author of JMSToolBox)